# What's the correct way to change the `PATH` environmental variable?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

When it comes to changing the `PATH` environment variable (say, in "~/.bashrc"), I've seen some different ways of doing it:

```
PATH=$PATH:/new/path
PATH="$PATH:/new/path"
export PATH = $PATH:/new/path
export PATH = ${PATH}:/new/path
setenv PATH $PATH:/new/path
```

What are the `{ }` for? When are the `" "` needed? When to use `export` or `setenv`? Btw, my Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't have a manual entry for `export`, but it has one for `setenv`. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When it comes to changing the `PATH` environment variable (say, in "~/.bashrc"), I've seen some different ways of doing it

Some of them are valid ways of setting `$PATH`, but some of them are *not* valid ways of setting `$PATH`; most have the same catch and some differ in their scope;

Speaking of the syntax (in Bash / compatible shells);

- `PATH=$PATH:/new/path`: is ok, but you'll need to escape spaces in "/new/path", if any;
- `PATH="$PATH:/new/path"`: is ok, and you won't need to escape spaces in "/new/path", if any;
- `export PATH = $PATH:/new/path`: is not ok, as you can't have spaces before / after an assignment operator (and you'd need to escape spaces in "/new/path");
- `export PATH = ${PATH}:/new/path`: same as `export PATH = $PATH:/new/path`;
- `setenv PATH $PATH:/new/path`: `setenv` is a `csh` built-in; it should be the same as `PATH=$PATH:/new/path`;

Single / double quotes both prevent Bash from breaking on whitespaces; single quotes prevent Bash from performing parameter expansions, command substitutions or arithmetic expansions, forcing Bash to interpret the enclosed string literally; double quotes instead don't prevent Bash to perform parameter expansions, command substitutions or arithmetic expansions, and in the second case they are needed in order to allow a parameter expansion on `$PATH`;

Braces are required in case the character following a variable is a valid character for a variable name, however `:` is not, so in the fourth case they're not really needed;

Speaking of the differences between `var=value`, `export var=value` and `setenv var value`;

- `var=value` sets the value of `$var` in the current shell; forked shells / processes won't inherit the variable nor its value;
- `export var=value` sets the value of `$var` in the current environment; forked shells / processes will inherit the variable and its value;
- `setenv PATH $PATH:/new/path`: same as `export var=value`;

```
$ foo=bar
$ bash
$ echo $foo

$ exit
exit
$ export foo=bar
$ bash
$ echo $foo
bar
```

> By the way, my Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't have a manual entry for `export`, but it has one for `setenv`. Why?

If you type `man setenv`, you get the output of `man 3 setenv`, which is the manual entry of the `setenv()` function from the "Linux Programmer's Manual"; as said before, there's no `setenv` command in Ubuntu nor built-in in Bash named `setenv`, although there's a `setenv` built-in in `csh`;

`export` instead *is* a Bash built-in, and to get informations about it you'll have to run `help export`:

```
$ help export
export: export [-fn] [name[=value] ...] or export -p
    Set export attribute for shell variables.

    Marks each NAME for automatic export to the environment of subsequently
    executed commands.  If VALUE is supplied, assign VALUE before exporting.

    Options:
      -f    refer to shell functions
      -n    remove the export property from each NAME
      -p    display a list of all exported variables and functions

    An argument of `--' disables further option processing.

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless an invalid option is given or NAME is invalid.
```

Comment: Also, note that your system will use the **first available** match.  `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin` will use executables found in `bin` before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: `export PATH = $PATH:/new/path` is not ok. Space is not allowed before and after the '=' character in Bash when assigning a variable.